# DataGrid binded to ObservableCollection<ParentType> add line of Children type with canUserAddRows="true"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to refactor some classes that have a lot of code duplicated and are hard to maintain. They all are user controls with similar behaviors and always displaying a different type of object in an ObservableCollection.

For that, I created two new classes to refatcor functions, which I can sum up to :

```
public class WorkItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected string _typeModif = "";
    public string typeModif
    {
        get { return _typeModif; }
        set { _typeModif = value; }
    }

    public WorkItem()
    {
        typeModif = "";
    }

    // Property changed stuff
}
```

and

```
public abstract class ChildUserControl_MasterData
{
    public ObservableCollection<WorkItem> LstMasterData_AFF = new ObservableCollection<WorkItem>();
}
```

I use it this way in the children classes :

```
public partial class MD_Article : ChildUserControl_MasterData
{
    DataSet ds = clsInterfaceBD.getLstArticle();
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            LstMasterData_AFF.Add(new Article(dr));
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Article : WorkItem
{
    public Article()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LstMasterData_AFF, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Everything is displayed correctly, but my problem occurs when I want to add a new line. I have to keep using the old method to insert lines that works with CanUserAddRows.
The object is created with the type `WorkItem`, which has to be the default behavior. But it creates several problems :

- I can't make WorkItem and abstract class, which it was supposed to be at the beginning, because CanUserAddRows wants to create an instance of the class.
- When I want to make operations on the Collection, it is of the type WorkItem and not Article, which I can't process.

Is there a way I'm missing to make the new line of the correct type using AddNewRows ?

Don't hesitate to tell me if my description is not clear.

Comment: For the `CanUserAddRows` property to work as expected, the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that is set as the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` must have a public default constructor. This is a requirement.

Comment: @mm8 WorkItem and Article both have default constructors (which is why I included them) so I think it should work or am I missing something ?

Comment: When I insert a new line (at the empty bottom row), the object is of type WorkItem, and not Article in my collection, so I can't process it. I would like to know if I can make it of tye Article when inserting it.

Comment: Only by changing the type of the source collection as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorkItem` cannot be `abstract`. And if you want `Article` objects to be created, you should change the type of the source collection from `ObservableCollection<WorkItem>` to `ObservableCollection<Article>`.

For the `CanUserAddRows` property to work as expected, the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that is set as the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` must have a public default constructor. This is a requirement.

You can set values for the new item of type `T` by handling the `InitializingNewItem` event and setting the values programmatically.

If you want to customize the creation of the objects any further than this, you should probably set `CanUserAddRows` to `false` and implement your own custom solution of adding items to the source collection.

Comment: That's unfortunately what I expected, so I'll try other ways.
I will look more into `InitializaingNewItem`, because I missed it and couldn't make it work with `AddingNewItem`.

If everything misses I'll go with the implement it myself solution, but I wanted to try not spending too much time on this.
Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled (quite randomly, I must say) upon a solution that works for me. I thought I'll share it here if someone ever faces the same problem that I did.

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True"
          AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewItem"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LstMasterData_AFF, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

And my AddingNewItem is as simple as follows :

```
private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewItem = new Article();
}
```

And this works perfectly. I even was able to put my WorkItem class as Abstract as I initially wanted.

I'll keep mm8 solution as accepted because I think it's overall the better answer, but this one worked for me and is better on my context (solution not using MVVM pattern).